# Have there been any other official foreign remakes of Marvel characters besides Supaidāman?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

The Japanese TV series of Supaidāman, produced by Toei, ran for 41 episodes with the full blessing of Marvel. Although it was based around the American Spider-Man, it went way further than just translating or modifying its source material for another culture. In this version, a motorcycle racer named Takuya Yamashiro gets his power from a UFO that traveled to Earth from the Planet Spider and ends up piloting a battle robot named "Leopardon".

Has Marvel ever attempted this kind of licensing tradeoff with any other properties or any other countries? Specifically, are there any other country-specific spins on Marvel properties that differ significantly from their original American version and maintained their own separate continuities?

Comment: Just a note, Supaidāman is just the Romanization of スパイダーマン, which is literally just how you write Spider-man in Japanese. Calling the series Supaidāman is maybe a little silly, probably confusing, and potentially insulting. I would probably stick with calling it *スパイダーマン (Spider-man)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Marvel Anime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Anime) continuity for Japan is separate from the main Marvel continuity.

> The project took top Marvel characters and reintroduced them for a Japanese audience via four 12-part series; *Iron Man*, *Wolverine*, *X-Men*, and *Blade*, which aired in Japan on Animax between October 2010 and September 2011. The announcement was confirmed at the 2009 San Diego Comic-Con. According to former Madhouse President and CEO Jungo Maruta, Marvel gave the anime studio free rein to re-imagine the Marvel superheroes for Japanese audiences. English version was premiered in the United States on G4. The series was guided by Warren Ellis. "It will create an entire parallel universe for Marvel," said Simon Philips, president of Marvel International about Marvel Anime.

An excerpt from *X-Men*:

Also, as starpilotsix pointed out, *[Spider-Man: India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_India)* was originally published in India by Gotham Entertainment Group and tells the story of Pavitr Prabhakar in Earth-50101.

> Pavitr Prabhakar, a simple Indian boy from a remote village, moves to Mumbai with his Aunt Maya and Uncle Bhim to study after getting half a scholarship. His parents died some years ago. Other students at his new school tease him and hit him for his studious nature and village background. He knows his Uncle Bhim is struggling to support him and his aunt Maya, and pay his school fees. Only Meera Jain, a popular girl from his school, befriends him. Meanwhile, a local crime lord named Nalin Oberoi uses an amulet to perform an ancient ritual in which he is possessed by a demon committed to opening a gate for other demons to invade Earth. While being chased by bullies, Pavitr Prabhakar encounters an ancient yogi who grants him the powers of a spider, in order to fight the evil that threatens the world. While discovering his powers, Pavitr Prabhakar refuses to help a woman being attacked by several men. He leaves the place, but comes back when he hears his uncle cry out, and discovers that he has been slain. He learns that Bhim was stabbed when he tried to help the woman. Pavitr Prabhakar understands that with great power comes great responsibility, and swears to use his powers for the good of others.

As it is officially part of the numbered Marvel universes and was involved in the *Spider-Verse* crossover, I think it's debatable as to whether it actually has a separate continuity, as compared the the Marvel Anime imprint, which seems completely separate.

Comment: There was also a Spider-Man: India book produced in India that was eventually published in the US, which reimagines Spidey as Pavitr Prabhakar, different origin but with similar characters (generally demon-caused rather than science).

Comment: "Spider-Man: India was originally published in India by Gotham Entertainment Group"

Oh, the irony.

Comment: Pavitr Prabhakar? Aunt Maya? Uncle Bhim? Meera Jain? Nalin Oberoi? Those names sound oddly familiar.